# Use jQuery load with fadeIn technique

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm trying to load a html page into an element using the jQuery load function. The problem is I'm getting a small flicker when the new content loads.

You can see the demo page here - http://wwwdev.legendboats.com (click on the bottom boats to load the new content into the main area)

Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
$("#mycarousel a").click(function() {

     $("#home_box div").fadeOut().load($(this).attr("href") + ' #featured_content', function(response, status, xhr) {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The flickr only happens when the content is loaded from cache because load() method fades in the new content before the old content is faded out, try loading the content in the callback function of the fadeout.

```
$("#mycarousel a").click(function() 
{
     $("#home_box div").fadeOut(function() 
     {
         $(this).load($(this).attr("href") + ' #featured_content', function(response, status, xhr) 
         {
             $(this).fadeIn();
         }
     });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I would also suggest remembering the page scroll position. On my computer I had to scroll down to click the boats and after the content was loaded the page scrolled back to the top.

Comment: `$(this).attr("href")` won't work because in your code `this` refers to the div.

Comment: I made the same mistake in my answer :-)

Comment: @Pointy I was about to post the same comment there, but then you commented you already found the problem :).

Comment: I'm still getting the problem of the content now not loading in. I've updated the demo with this new code, and as you can see, the content doesn't load back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying the loading until after it's faded:

```
$("#mycarousel a").click(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#home_box div").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).load(url + ' #featured_content', function(response, status, xhr) {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

*edit* — fixed problem with "this" confusion

Comment: That doesn't work, makes the content fadeOut, but nothing will reappear.

Comment: Well it certainly should work; are you seeing any errors?  All that does is defer the ".load()" call until after the "fadeOut()" completes, just like you've got the ".fadeIn()" deferred until after the ".load()" completes.  It's the way the library works.